# iterate an STL container not from the .begin()ing and wrap around

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, std

I have an std::vector, let's say of integers for simplicity.

```
std::vector<int> ivec;
ivec.push_back(1);
ivec.push_back(2);
... //omitting some push back's 3 to 99
ivec.push_back(100);
```

The standard way to iterate is known

```
std::map<int>::iterator it;
for( it = ivec.begin(); it != ivec.end(); it++ ) 
  print();
```

That iteration will print 1,2,3, ... 100.

I want to traverse all vector elements starting from a predefined index and not from it.begin().
I would like to print

> 3,4,5,6 ... 99, 100, 1, 2

Can you share your thoughts here?

It might ok to do it in two steps

```
for( it = ivec.begin()+index; it != ivec.end(); it++ ) and then (if index !=0)

for ( it = ivec.begin; it = it = ivec.begin() + (index-1); it++)
```

Comment: You could write an iterator wrapper that displays the desired behavior. But unless you need that more than a couple of times, it's probably overkill.

Comment: Check out Boost Circular Buffer : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html

Comment: Your last example is wrong. In the second loop the condition should be `it != ivec.begin()+index` (of course this works for random iterators only, anyway) and you don't need that `if index != 0`, the loop condition does that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool wrapped = false;
for (auto it = vec.begin() + index; (it != vec.begin() + index) || !wrapped; ++it)
{
    if (it == vec.end())
    {
        it = vec.begin();
        wrapped = true;
    }
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

Comment: Shound't it be `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: @ChristianRau That would break from the loop at the very start, no?

Comment: No, since at the beginning `!wrapped` is `true`. After wrapping `!wrapped` is `false` and the OR is equivalent to the iterator condition only. In your case it would terminate at the beginning, since the iterator condition is false and therefore the AND.

Comment: This doesn't quite work if `index` is `0`, you get `vec.begin()` twice. Maybe add `if (index == 0) break;` at the top of the inner if statement.

Answer (score 7):

You can either:

- develop an iterator class that wraps the vector::iterator and expose the behaviour you like (in particular: ++ checks for end() and replace it with begin() and adjust the other "border values")
- fill the vector starting from 3 and wrap at 100, so that standard iteration will look as you want.

The choice depends on what else the vector is purposed and what else that iteration is needed.

Comment: @PaulManta: if the problem is "localized" is trivial. 
If the problem is "generalized" if far from being trivial: if you want your iteration to work with whatever existing STL algorithm... you HAVE TO define an iterator.

I think your down-vote is based on a prejudice.

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume that you already have a starting iterator. How you get this depends on whether you are using an indexable (vector) type or a forward iterator only, or a keyed type. Then you can do a loop something like this:

```
type::iterator start_iter = /* something from collection, perhaps begin()+index */
type::iterator cur_iter = start_iter;
do
{
  //do something with cur_iter

  ++cur_iter;
  if( cur_iter == collection.end() )
    cur_iter = collection.begin();
} while( cur_iter != start_iter );
```

That's the basic loop.

Comment: Sorry, should have been `.begin()`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a pretty old question, but nobody mentioned `std::rotate`, which I think, in some cases, can be the right tool for the job.

Modified example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::rotate
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector;

  // set some values:
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) myvector.push_back(i); // 1, 2, 3, ... 9

  std::rotate(myvector.begin(), myvector.begin() + 2, myvector.end());
                                                  // 3, 4, 5, 6 ... 9, 1, 2
  // print out content:
  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (auto it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

[cpp.sh/3rdru](http://cpp.sh/3rdru)

Output:

```
myvector contains: 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2
```

Note, since `my_vector` is modified by the `std::rotate` function, this is neither very efficient nor useful if you just want to iterate the vector once.

However, while this is probably not the best answer to this SO question, I hope it can still provide some value for people with similar issues.

Comment: Your code modifies original vector though. It might not be ideal in some cases.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll update my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

A solution when using a random-access container is very simple, see the code below.

```
std::vector<int> v ({1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}); /* c++11 */

...

for (int i = 2; i < (10+2); ++i)
  std::cout << v[i % 10] << " ";
```

---

Method when using containers only having bidirectional/forward iterators:

```
  std::list<int> l ({1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}); /* c++11 */

  Iter start = l.begin ();
  std::advance (start, 4);

  ...

  Iter it = start;

  do {
    std::cerr << *it << std::endl;

  } while (
    (it = ++it == l.end () ? l.begin () : it) != start
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are endless ways to do it, and probably all are (more or less) equivalent, so in the end it depends on personal preference and maybe coding style conventions. I would probably do it like:

```
std::cout << v[idx] << "\n";
for( auto it = v.begin() + idx + 1; it != v.begin()+idx; ++it )
{
    if( it == v.end() ) it = v.begin();
    std::cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @cateo: I always use it to store iterators since it makes code look less convoluted, and in many cases allows me to write generic code easier as I don't have to access nested typedefs.

Comment: OP probably doesn't know about it, since it's C++11.